# C++: Using cin.getline()

Tags: c++, arrays, string, cin

Now I have learned that `cin.getline` works like this.

`cin.getline(dest string, number of charecters to put into string);`

so assume this program.

```
char s1[8]="Hellopo";
cin.getline(s1,5);
cout<<s1<<endl;
```

This was by input :`hhhhhhhhhhhhh`

This was the programs output: `hhhh`

I have 2 concerns in this program.

1-) I set the program to get 5 characters from what the user inputed and store in s1. When I ran The program it only printed out 4 characters.

2-) Also I expected the program to continue printing out the rest of s1 after it printed out what it got from the user. but it stopped after `hhhh`

Please explain to me my two concerns. Thank you

Comment: Don't use member-`getline`s. Use the free `std::getline` with an `std::string` instead.

Comment: In part 2, what do you mean by "the rest of s1"? Whatever input cin places in s1 is all there is.

Comment: actually no the rest of the string is there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[std::cin::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) will store four characters plus a null termination in this case (five characters in total). And `std::cout` will stop printing at the first null terminator it finds.

Answer (score 3):

From [`istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline):

> count-1 characters have been extracted (in which case setstate(failbit) is executed).

This means that if you specify `5`, only `4` characters will be read. And:

> ...it then stores a null character CharT() into the next successive location of the array

so a null character will be inserted after the fourth character. So the array `s` will have contents:

```
'h' == s[0]
'h' == s[1]
'h' == s[2]
'h' == s[3]
0   == s[4]
```

The `operator<<` will stop printing a `char*` when the first null character is found.

Answer (score 2):

The fifth character is the 0-terminator. `getline(buffer,n)` stores up to `n` bytes including the 0-terminator in the buffer. And then `cout << s1;` stops at the 0-terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The fifth character is the null terminator, which marks the end of the string.